# Customize PAM messages

Tags: linux, pam

I would like to customize my password expiration warnings. I figured PAM reads them from somewhere, but can't find from where. The question is relevant for both Ubuntu/Debian and Fedora/RHEL/CentOS.

Where does PAM read `Warning: your password will expire in X days` from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Account and password expiration information is contained in the `/etc/shadow` file.  see `man shadow` for more information.

As for the message string, they are hard coded in one (or possibly more) of the PAM object code modules.  To change the messages, you'll have to change the source code for these PAM modules, recompile, and install the resulting binary.

Comment: Specifically: ./modules/pam_unix/pam_unix_acct.c